# Error on `it-1` with set iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, set

In following code I can not recognize difference between `--it`, and `it-1`.
Also is `words.end()` value is out of set range?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<string> words;
    words.insert("test");
    words.insert("crack");
    words.insert("zluffy");
    set<string>::iterator it=words.end();
    cout<<*(--it)<<endl;//just works fine 
    cout<<*(it-1)<<endl;//Error 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because [`std::set::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is a constant [BidrectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). That means it supports `++it` and `--it`. However, it is *not* a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) (like `std::vector::iterator`) - which is what it would need to be to support `it + n` and `it - n`.

While `--it` and `it -= 1` conceputally do the same thing, the latter requires more functionality than `std::set` provides. That's why it's not supported. You could always use something like: [`std::prev(it, 1)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev), which would work on any iterator that satisfies the BidirectionalIterator concept.

Answer (score 1):

`words.end()` gives an iterator to an "element" past the end of the set. It does not point to anything so you cannot dereference it.
It serves at a bound for your set. You can for example scan your set from `words.end()` to `words.begin()` :

```
for (set<string>::iterator it = words.begin() ; it != words.end() ; ++it)
{
    cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer mate, i got it.